# Kotlin, MockK: How to verify that a method call throws an exception with MockK?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I am learning Kotlin and MockK. I have seen how to verify that a method was called and how to check the result. But how would I check, that the method has thrown an exception?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I found it: `assertFailsWith<EceptionClass> { methodCall() }`

Answer (score -2):

This is my approach, hope its helping you

```
class TestClass {
    fun testVerify() {
        throw Exception("exception")
    }
}
```

```
@Test
fun mockTest() {
    try {
        TestClass().testVerify()
    }
    catch (e: Exception) {
        assertEquals(e.message, "exception")
    }
}
```